# Magento 2 : Translate string in function in knockout template

Tags: magento2, javascript, template, localisation, knockoutjs

In a Magento Knockout template I find a function like so:

```
<element data-bind="something: function() {
    return 'some string';
}" />
```

How can I translate this string? I tried following, but it does not work:

```
<element data-bind="something: function() {
    return $t('some string');
}" />
```

The translation exists and works in other places, so that is not the problem.

Comment: Which file did you find the example? Can you give me the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding i18n: in front of the value of data-bind attribute.
Something like below;

```
<element data-bind="i18n: something: function() {
    return $t('some string');
}" />
```

**Note:** Please note that the translation for corresponding string should be present  in your language translation csv.